dash/plotly: add custom d3js date format specifier
I have a dash/plotly figure for which I use a d3js date format specifier among d3-time-format:
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%s", hoverformat="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L")

Here, for the axis, I chose the seconds since UNIX epoch and an iso-string for the hoveraxis. For the axis format, I would like to use a custom format, e.g. the seconds since a custom epoch.
How can I achieve this? In what file should I define my custom d3js specifier and how to use it within my dash app?
